# What tick rate are the Fortnite servers using?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have been playing Fortnite quite a bit, and noticed there is sometimes lag between progress bar's finishing and actions completing (moving too soon and interrupting a potion, etc).

I was curious as CSGO has the "tick" rate fairly public, but Fortnite only shows packet rate.

What is the tick rate on the Fortnite servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it somewhere that they have 18 tick rate servers. 
Cannot remember exactly where but the same value seems to be in this thread also:

https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/79pl3r/fnbr_performance_update/

Comment: Oh wow I had heard 18hz tossed around but was hoping it was false. That would mean 18 ticks a second right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Perhaps this answer should be updates based on new information? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.vg247.com/2018/05/25/fortnite-battle-royale-netcode-impossible-upgrades-delay/amp/

Answer (score 0):

18 Hz tickrate is an average value. 
I think all these tickrate values are from videos from [Battle(non)sense](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP7QY6L5pvmm0-stL-pNFrw). And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiYX9ik0iec) is one of the videos where he shows all the values for fortniet and pubg